# Testing if a variable is empty in a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, portability, test

I have seen the following technique used many times on many different shells, to test if a variable is empty:

```
if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then 
    # Variable is empty
fi
```

Are there any advantages on using this over the more canonical `if [ -z "$1" ]`? Could it be a portability issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Some historical shells implemented a very simple parser that could get confused by things like `[ -n = "" ]` where the first operand to `=` looks like an operator, and would parse this as `[ -n = ]` or cause a syntax error. In `[ "x$1" = x"" ]`, the `x` prefix ensures that `x"$1"` cannot possibly look like an operator, and so the only way the shell can parse this test is by treating `=` as a binary operator.

All modern shells, and even most older shells still in operation, follow the [POSIX rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html#tag_04_140_05) which mandate that all test expressions of up to 4 words be parsed correctly. So **`[ -z "$1" ]` is a proper way of testing if `$1` is empty**, and `[ "$x" = "$y" ]` is a proper way to test the equality of two variables.

Even some current shells can get confused with longer expressions, and a few expressions are actually ambiguous, so avoid using the `-a` and `-o` operators to construct longer boolean tests, and instead use separate calls to `[` and the shell's own `&&` and `||` boolean operators.

Comment: It's not only _historical_ shells. Some ksh88 based `sh`s on some commercial Unices still have the issue. See [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/test/) for details.

Comment: This statement is incorrect: *`[ -z "$1" ]` is a proper way of testing if `$1` is empty*. `sh -c '[ -z "$1" ]' ''; sh -c '[ -z "$1" ]'` - both return 0, but in the second case `$1` cannot be empty because it does not exist.

Comment: sh with the -c option is present, If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0. not $1

Answer (score 4):

According to http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~uwe/lehre/unixffb/quoting-guide.html, the `-z` test is *unsafe in some implementations*, presumably when "interesting" strings like `"-o a=a"` are tested.

Answer (score 3):

The above tests will also cause an error if you run with "set -u" or "set -o nounset"

A more stable way to check for an empty variable would be to use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

MYVAR=${MYVAR:-"Bad Value"}

This method works for the traditional bourne shell, as well as ksh, and bash.

Comment: I believe this is written as -> M=${M:-"Bad Value"}

Answer (score 0):

```
    function isBlank {
 valueNoSpaces=$(echo "$@" | tr -d ' ')

 if [  "$valueNoSpaces" == null ] || [ -z "$valueNoSpaces" ] 
 then
       echo true ;
 else
       echo ""  ;
 fi
}

#Test
if [ $(isBlank "      ") ] 
then
    echo "isBlank \"      \" : it's blank"
else
    echo " isBlank \"      \": it is not blank"
fi

if [ $(isBlank "abc") ] 

then
    echo "isBlank \"abc\" : it's blank"
else
    echo "isBlank \"abc\" :it is not blank"
fi

if [ $(isBlank null) ] 
then
      echo "isBlank null : it's blank"
else
    echo "isBlank null : it is not blank"
fi

if [ $(isBlank "") ] 
then
    echo "isBlank \"\" : it's blank"
else
    echo "isBlank \"\" : it is not blank"
fi

#Result
isBlank "      " : it's blank

isBlank "abc" :it is not blank

isBlank null : it's blank

isBlank "" : it's blank
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure how this answers the question, which asks *why* to use `=` versus `-z`, now how.