# When are arbitrary strings passed to test ambiguous

Tags: linux, shell

I came across this construct to test whether the shell variable `$foo`, which could contain any arbitrary string, matched `foo`:

```
[ "x$foo" = "xfoo" ]
```

The purpose of prefixing with `x` was never explained.  This looks like an attempt to avoid errors that might arise when `$foo` contains strings special to test like `=`, `-f`, `(`, or `!`.  The GNU info manual indicates compound expressions involving `-a` and `-o` can lead to ambiguity, so I am primarily interested in simple (i.e., not compound) statements.  I had a hard time searching for more information on this.  I have not been able to devise an example of an arbitrary string that caused GNU `test` to fail in an unexpected manner, although I freely admit I'm not that clever.

My questions:

1. What reasons are there to prefix parameter substitutions in `test`?
2. Is there an example of a simple (i.e., not compound) statement involving naive parameter substitution (i.e., no prefix protection) that causes `test` to give unusual results?

I mostly use GNU tools on linux, but for the sake of portability, I am interested in whether `test` on other platforms as well.

Comment: Related: [Testing if a variable is empty in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32180/testing-if-a-variable-is-empty-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: By my reading you are correct; there is no way that a non-compound expression can be ambiguous with POSIX-compliant `test`.  I *think* that on very very old implementations, null-string arguments may be handled badly/differently, but I don't have a copy of the original Bourne shell to check.  I seem to recall reading about this on this site before, though.  You have my +1 for a good question.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the link.  The title didn't seem relevant, but the answer there was.  If you make that into a decent answer here, I'll accept it.

Comment: `test` is specially ambiguos when the actual `test` called is `/bin/test`. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853353/8017719) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/174288/8017719).

Comment: @Arrow Thanks.  For general reference, that and [the question it's a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174119/why-do-shell-script-comparisons-often-use-xvar-xyes) and [another duplicate of that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805663/shell-script-purpose-of-x-in-xvariable/) expand on the other answer linked above.

Answer (score 1):

```
> [ -f = -a -a -a ]
bash: [: argument expected

> [ -f = -a -a x ]
```

But:

```
[ x-f = x-a -a -a ]
```

doesn't work either although

```
[ -a ]
```

is fine.

Comment: As noted, compound expressions can cause ambiguity.  Can you think of a simple (i.e., not compound) expression that causes unexpected results?

Comment: Actually, `[ -a ]` is a good example of an ambiguous statement.  GNU `test` returns 0 because this is interpreted as `[ -n "-a" ]` rather than `[ -n "" -a -n "" ]`.  However, prefixing does not solve anything, as `[ "x$foo" ]` and `[ -n "x$foo" ]` are always true, which defeats the purpose of the test.

Comment: @ov2k, I can't understand your comment at all.  `[ -a ]` is not ambiguous in any way whatsoever.

Comment: @Wildcard Many users would likely not recognize that `[ -a ]` is interpreted by test as equivalent to `[ -n "-a" ]`, which returns 0, and not `[ -n "" -a -n "" ]`, which returns 1.  The information necessary to understand why is not present in the man page for GNU `test`, although it is present in the POSIX standard and the GNU info page.  As it relates to my original questions, it is true that `[ "$foo" ]` is handled properly, and it remains unclear why a construct of the form "x$foo" might be necessary.

Comment: @ov2k, reread the question.  I think the real answer is, providing that `test` has three arguments or less (or `[` has four or less including `]`), there is no possible ambiguity.  Good point.  But `[ -a ]` still isn't ambiguous, even if some users don't know shell syntax well enough to understand it.  ;)